# diagonalizable matrix : exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have trouble solving this, any help?

Given $B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t & 25\\
0 & t & t+1\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ find t in order to make B diagonalizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the eigenvalues of this matrix (depending on $t$). Hint: note that this is an upper triangular matrix.

Secondly, by making a case distinction on $t$, calculate the eigenvectors. The matrix is diagonizable iff you find three linear independent ones.